# Missing formatter options for field from a custom table defined in hook_views_data()

Tags: 8, views, hooks

I integrated a custom database table to views using `hook_views_data()`.

```php
$data['custom_watchdog']['message'] = [
    'title' => 'Message',
    'help' => 'Full log message.',
    'field' => [
        'id' => 'standard',
    ],
    'filter' => [
        'id' => 'string',
    ],
];
```

It works, as I can display values in a view, but it misses a formatter option.
For example, the *Taxonomy term: Description* field has formatter options which allows to select *Default* or *Trimmed*.

Why isn't it available for my custom field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a standard Views field with an entity field. Only entity fields have field formatters. Create a custom entity instead of a custom table if you want to use this feature. For a standard field you have to use the options provided by Views. There is a trim option as well, but it is named differently, `trim` in the `alter` section. You see it in Views UI. Try to configure it and check the exported View.

Comment: Thank you @4k4 for explanation. Trim was just an example, I was building custom FieldFormatter.
At the end I used hook_preprocess_views_view_field() to modify output of the view field.